# Papercut smtp credentials / port for web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

What would be an appropriate web.config for configuring smtp for [papercut](http://papercut.codeplex.com)?

The papercut documentation doesn't seem to say whether it needs a username / password. Or whether it can use the defaultCredentials="true"

I also run into trouble with connecting to localhost via IISExpress to port 25. I'm suprised the windows firewall is blocking it because it's just connecting to localhost. But I'm guessing it's something to do with IISExpress running under my user account and therefore not having permissions to connect to ports by default.

Would running on a high port for papercut enable IISExpress permission to create connections to localhost? Or is it simply the case of tweaking the firewall?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Hi @DaffyPunk sorry this was many years ago from 2 jobs ago I can't remember I'm afraid! I do remember liking Papercut so perhaps I did come up with a workaround but perhaps just for my situation rather than answering the question. However looking at the new github repo it appears to have been re-written so this file looks like it could work: https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut/blob/9abae48be91d6ebc67f3831767b81ce5b0282927/src/Papercut.Service/Papercut.Service.Settings.json